# Can a callback function from server be manipulated?

Tags: javascript

Building a cart, we calculate price on the client side, then i need to send this price variable in a `form` to `PayPal` on client side.

I know that anyone can manipulate that price variable and i have to **validate** it on the **server side.**

For instance a function like this that call to my server :

```
 var url = "https://xxxxxx/getProductPrice";
        $.get(url,{productID :ID},

        function(data) {

        var price = data.price;  

       //*** can someone play with this price respond at this point ?

       //can send it to a PayPal form safely ?

      //can this form here be manipulated also ?

       });
```

So, if someone can use `FireBug` to manipulate my first price *which i read from the server anyway*, why couldn't they also **manipulate this callback from the server**?

If they could, how can i protect it ?
I find it hard to understand what could be manipulated.

Comment: All client side data can be manipulated, also the server callback. So before storing any data to your server: verify it server-side. E.g. you let the server verify the price versus the paid price (from PayPal), to see whether or not the payment is completely paid.

Comment: Don't trust the client!

Comment: Yes they can. You need to pass an [order ID](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/) that you created on the server to avoid this - Check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/#) for how to do it using SDK

Comment: I don't understand any of you, no matter what the server return to me, the moment its on the client side, it can be manipulated, so basically i can't do nothing. How can i "check" something? by returning a variable from a server, which means, like in the example, that at this point it can be manipulated. What am I missing ?

Comment: @AlonEitan i am not sure you are right. If PayPal offer me a way to submit a transaction using a form, that means that the client has a way to send sale data to paypal, and this has to be done somehow safely.

Comment: @Daan so you basically say - let people pay, if they paid 8$ instead of 10$, so when paypal callback my server, with a payment of 8$ i will have to go again and compare it to 10 on the server? this seems so wrong, because at this point the seller already get a notification from paypal that the transaction was successful. You basically say that there is no way to output a *safe* data from a client side to PayPal or Stripe or any payment gateway, because the price can be manipulated at client side? i have a feeling we are not talking about the same thing.

Comment: @paulseems I'm not an expert with payments, but yes, everything client-sided can be manipulated. Probably you could validate the price before they click on "Pay" and then send them to PayPal link with this exact price. Then it wouldn't be able to be manipulated. The thing is that you can only trust PayPal (hopefully :P) and your own server.